# How can I assign if statement for error and correct class

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I want IF statement to check if class name is "errorexist", if it does then it will carry out IF statement else it will carryout ELSE statement.
Here I am getting an error to convert webelement to boolean

Trying this in Eclipse with Java

```
 String a = "http://www.myfortunecookie.co.uk/fortunes/";
 int i;
 String s;
 for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     String b = Integer.toString(i);
     s = a + b;
     driver.get(s);
     if (driver.findElement(By.className("errorexist"))) {
         System.out.println(i);
     } else {
         System.out.println(i + " " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='fortune']")).getText());
     }
 }
```

If error page appears then it will print value of i
If class fortune found then it will get text of class

Answer (score 1):

Use driver.findElements instead of driver.findElement to check whether element is visible on the page or not as driver.findElement will throw no such element found exception.

When you are writing the condition inside a if block it must return a boolean value, in your case it is returning WebElement and hence the error.

```
//Checks if Element is present, if Yes returns true
if(driver.findElements(By.className("errorexist")).isEmpty()){
//Code to be executed when element is not present
}
else{
//Code to be executed when Element is present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch not `if`.

```
String a = "http://www.myfortunecookie.co.uk/fortunes/";
 int i;
 String s;
 for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     String b = Integer.toString(i);
     s = a + b;
     driver.get(s);
     try {
         driver.findElement(By.className("errorexist"));
         System.out.println(i);
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(i + " " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='fortune']")).getText());
     }

 }
```